# Someone reset the Apple ID password

Tags: apple-id, password

I got the email saying Ant changed the password now on November 1 at 7:24 PM, it says: Your Apple ID password has been reset.

> Dear Anthony Jackson,
>
> The password for your Apple ID (grandmahecock@gmail.com) has been successfully reset.
>
> If you didn’t make this change or if you believe an unauthorized person has accessed your account, go to iforgot.apple.com to reset your password immediately. Then sign into your Apple ID account page at https://appleid.apple.com to review and update your security settings.
>
> If you need additional help, contact Apple Support.
>
> Apple Support

Comment: Go to the site but do NOT click on the address in the email. Type it into your browser.

Comment: This could be a phising attempt - note the email shown is not ant - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/72554/237

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's an Apple ID you manage?

Without seeing the mail, I would recommend to go to the official Apple website and try to login. When there is no access possible, you can take further steps.

Here are for example some steps mentioned: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253284241

When access is possible you can of course change the password to make sure.
Also make sure, when you manage the account for someone, the person didn't made changes to it.